# w3-cell elements with images inside will not adjust to equal height

Tags: html, css, w3.css

I am attempting to create an image gallery using w3.css. I am constructing it with w3-cell-row and w3-cell elements. When I place images of varying size in these w3-cell elements the images will display with unequal heights, contrary to how you would believe they would from reading this:
https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_layout.asp

I will put some code here that shows the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- link css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <head>
    <title> test </title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="w3-cell-row">
      <div class="w3-cell">
        <img src="http://shashgrewal.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/default-placeholder-300x300.png" style="width:100%;" >
      </div>
      <div class="w3-cell">
        <img src="http://www.pixedelic.com/themes/geode/demo/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2014/04/placeholder.png" style="width:100%;" >
      </div>
      <div class="w3-cell">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ4zIFE2vpdnB_b_qmWEa2NBKd_vFa_7f5XQpZUcyKs6vNNN85G" style="width:100%;" >
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see the images are displayed with varying heights. My expectation would be that the widths of the images would change to create a uniform cell height across the row.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew, you are missing another concept of 'Layout cells Adjust to equal heights', please refer to that section.

In your example I added cell colors to be red green and blue and you can see whats happening. width wont impact height but height impacts other cells height.

Also you can refer to [Images URL](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_images.asp) for responsive images.

Hope this helps!!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


<!-- link css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<head>
<title> test </title>
</head>

<body>


<div class="w3-cell-row">

<div class="w3-cell w3-red">
    <img src="http://shashgrewal.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/default-placeholder-300x300.png" style="width:100%;" >
</div>

<div class="w3-cell w3-green">
    <img src="http://www.pixedelic.com/themes/geode/demo/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2014/04/placeholder.png" style="width:100%;" >
</div>

<div class="w3-cell w3-blue">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ4zIFE2vpdnB_b_qmWEa2NBKd_vFa_7f5XQpZUcyKs6vNNN85G" style="width:100%;" >
</div>

</div>


</body>
```